# How to compile a Qt application for a Symbian 9.1. device?

Tags: debugging, qt, symbian, nokia

I tried to launch my Qt application on a device that uses Symbian 9.1 ([Nokia E65](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_E65)).
But TRK (the debug agent) for S60 v3 FP1 can not install.
I tried to download the TRK agent from other source and installed it on my device, but 
it doesn't work with the Qt Debugger.

How can I make the Qt Debugger work with my Nokia E65 device?
Or how do I get a compiled .sis application file for my Nokia e65?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E65 is running S60 3.0 (3rd Edition initial release). You'll need a S60 3.1 device (3rd Edition FP1) or newer for Qt development. I'm afraid you're out of luck developing Qt application for E65.

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing the Qt cmponent in my E65 but it kept on saying qt component missing. And finally popped up a msg , unable to install. Its like Qt is built for S60v3os9.2 and  higher. Its so frustrating